# How python calculate this division?

Tags: python, divide

How python calculate this division?

```
>>>-3/10
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like python rounds the answer to the lower value.

```
>>> -3/4
-1
>>> -3/4.
-0.75
>>> -3/10.
-0.3
>>> -3/10
-1
```

This is just my guess.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2, like many languages, uses integer division. Dividing two integers returns a integer (the nearest integer to the answer rounded down.)

To get a floating point result, you need to force one or more of the terms to be a float.

```
  float(-3)/10
```

Comment: And yes. Python always rounds down.